# Theme customization in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9

I created theme in magento.Now i need to customize it.I created folder in the

```
 /var/www/html/porto_demo/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto_child
```

and

```
 /var/www/html/porto_demo/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto_child.
```

I am having one design based on that i have to customize the theme.Can any one suggest for this?
Advance Thanks!

Comment: please anyone suggest for this

Answer (score -1):

Check This: [Porto Docs](http://newsmartwave.net/magento/porto/documentation/) The complete documentation for Porto Theme.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I already referred that it was good to know the informations.But i need to create the theme with customized based on given design.Based on the design the changes are done in the admin .I also think that i just change the theme without using child theme.Can anyone give suggestions for this? Advance thanks!

Comment: I also need where the content of footer and header is present for the theme./var/www/html/porto_demo2/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/page/html/footer.phtml in this footer file php and jquery based codes are present but content is not present here.Can anyone suggest for this?